# Maven HikariCP, ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, maven

So as of right now I'm trying to grab the HikariCP dependency via maven and for a really strange reason, it's throwing out a ClassNotFoundException. The other 2 jars spigot-api & slf4j-simple are returning correctly excluding HikariCP that's the only dependency that's throwing a ClassNotFoundException.

I've tried importing the jar manually in to my build and it's still throwing out that error.

Error:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig
        at eos.sneling.krimsonnet.Storage.ConnectionPool.ConnectionPoolManager.setupPool(ConnectionPoolManager.java:50) ~[?:?]
        at eos.sneling.krimsonnet.Storage.ConnectionPool.ConnectionPoolManager.<init>(ConnectionPoolManager.java:32) ~[?:?]
        at eos.sneling.krimsonnet.core.initDatabase(core.java:29) ~[?:?]
        at eos.sneling.krimsonnet.core.onEnable(core.java:19) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:321) ~[spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:340) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:405) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:356) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:316) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.s(MinecraftServer.java:418) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.k(MinecraftServer.java:382) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:337) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:256) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:528) [spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_66]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:101) ~[spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:86) ~[spigot-1.8.7-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-latest.jar:git-Spigot-f928e7a-e91aed8]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
        ... 15 more
```

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>eos.sneling.krimsonnet</groupId>
    <artifactId>KrimsonNET</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>plugin.yml</include>
                    <include>config.yml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>
                                eos.sneling.krimsonnet.core
                            </mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spigot-repo</id>
            <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Comment: What is your JAVA_HOME set to?

Comment: On Mac type this in terminal `/usr/libexec/java_home`. In Ubuntu `echo $JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: http://puu.sh/lXrBH/a85be40ac5.png

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to build a bukkit minecraft mod?  The exception is coming from the bukkit PluginClassLoader when it is trying to run your mod.  After you build the jar file for your mod, you can check its contents by running

```
jar tf yourjarfile.jar
```

to see if at least the Hikari classes were properly included, as it looks like they should have been since you are using the maven-assembly-plugin to build a jar-with-dependencies.